# os.rename fail with [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, rename, listdir

using os.rename in python and getting '[Errno 2] No such file or directory'

full code:

```
import os
from string import digits # digits are one of 0123456789

path = "/Users/xxx/Documents/version-control/secret-msg/prank/"
l = os.listdir(path) # returns list of files in folder
for o in l: #o for 'original'
    c = o.lstrip(digits) # c for 'clean', without leading digits; lstrip = left strip - so left strip any digit
    if (o != c):
        os.rename (o, c) #rename original filename to clean one
        print o + '-> ' + c # for debug only
```

Comment: You're listing the content of directory "/Users/xxx/Documents/version-control/secret-msg/prank/", but when using os.rename, you do not reference it, so the method looks for a file with name *o*  in the _current_ directory. either change directory, or reference the complete path to the files (original and renamed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listdir` returns a list of files *without the path*

So, you should do:

```
import os
import os.path
from string import digits # digits are one of 0123456789

path = "/Users/xxx/Documents/version-control/secret-msg/prank/"
l = os.listdir(path) # returns list of files in folder
for o in l: #o for 'original'
    c = o.lstrip(digits) # c for 'clean', without leading digits; lstrip = left strip - so left strip any digit
    if (o != c):
        os.rename (os.path.join(path, o),
                   os.path.join(path, c) #rename original filename to clean one
        print o + '-> ' + c # for debug only
```

We use `os.path.join` to join the path to the filename.